# Unable to install Ruby gem selenium-webdriver on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: ruby, linux, selenium-webdriver, rubygems

I'm trying to install the gem selenium-webdriver on Ubuntu 19.04 but I keep getting this error:

```
sudo gem install selenium-webdriver
```

> Building native extensions. This
>   could take a while... ERROR:  Error installing selenium-webdriver:
>     ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/childprocess-1.0.1/ext /usr/bin/ruby2.5 mkrf_conf.rb
> ```
>
> current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/childprocess-1.0.1/ext
>   /usr/bin/ruby2.5 -rrubygems
>   /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake
>   RUBYARCHDIR\=/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/childprocess-1.0.1
>   RUBYLIBDIR\=/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/childprocess-1.0.1
>   /usr/bin/ruby2.5: No such file or directory --
>   /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake
>   (LoadError)
>
> rake failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/childprocess-1.0.1 for inspection. Results
>   logged to
>   /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/childprocess-1.0.1/gem_make.out

I have tried

```
sudo gem update --system
sudo apt install ruby-dev
sudo apt install build-essential
sudo apt install gcc
sudo apt install make


ruby -v ruby 2.5.5p157 (2019-03-15 revision 67260) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
gem -v 3.0.3
```

Comment: Stacktrace is pointomh to `No such file or directory -- /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake (LoadError)`.  Try `sudo install rake` first?  Just a shot in the dark...

Comment: rake is already the newest version (12.3.1-3)

Comment: Side note: did you see this: https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do this

```
sudo gem pristine rake
```

> Restoring gems to pristine condition... Cached gem for rake-12.3.1 not
>   found, attempting to fetch... Fetching rake-12.3.1.gem Restored
>   rake-12.3.1